# Asymptotes of Functions

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

For some rational function f(x), the graph of y=f(x) has an oblique asymptote of y=5x+7. Enter the equation of the horizontal asymptote of the graph of y=f(x)/x-2.

Comment: Hello SpongeBob4LIFE_24, it is good to ask questions. But stackexchange is not a site ment to just post excercises. Instead, tell us what you have tried, and where you got stuck. This helps us answer your question, and is better for your personal understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Because $f(x)$ is a rational function, $f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$ for polynomials $g$ and $h$. Then:

$\frac{f(x)}{x-2} = \frac{g(x)}{(x - 2)h(x)}$

Thus, $\frac{f(x)}{x-2}$ is a rational function with a factor of $x - 2$ in the denominator, and it thus is vertical asymptote is:

$\boxed{x = 2}$

Note: if $g(x)$ contains a factor of $x - 2$, then $\frac{f(x)}{x-2}$ will only have a hole at $x = 2$.